# Laravel - Empty $request after middleware

Tags: laravel, namespaces, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

In my controller I'm not able to get the data from `$request` because it is empty after a middleware.

For some reason when I call the controller method the data are set in `$request` and in the middleware I can access it and check, but as soon as I do:

```
return $next($request);
```

the `$request->all()` in controller is an empty array.

I tried to remove all the `middleware` functions but nothing change.

What can be the reason?

This is now my middleware:

```
class CheckApi {
    public function handle( $request, Closure $next )
    {
        return $next( $request );
    }
}
```

and this is the controller:

```
class StatusController extends ApiController {

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store( Request $request )
    {
         dd($request->all());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should make sure, that you are using `Request` from valid namespace. Try to change in your controller:

```
public function store( Request $request )
{
     dd($request->all());
}
```

into

```
public function store(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request )
{
     dd($request->all());
}
```

to make sure you are using valid Request object